# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am running the web service from the visual studio in built server, I am able to run the service and access the database.

But when I hosted the web service on iis 7.5, I am able to run the web service but I am not able to access the database. I am getting the following error.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

I don't have any clue how to solve this. Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SMO then you can do the followed code:

```
SqlConnectionInfo sci = new SqlConnectionInfo();
            sci.ConnectionProtocol = NetworkProtocol.NamedPipes;
            sci.EncryptConnection = false;
```

// set the EncryptConnection to false when you use the sqlserver SMO, when the property is set to true a servercertificate for the SQL server instance must be set.

Answer (score 0):

On the IIS server, I believe the certificate may need to be installed.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/12c4febb-18e7-4a77-a23e-a615b3913e67/problem-of-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted-i-have-imported-the

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred after the installation of a program which changes the Internet Protocol settings of your computer. Recently I got the same issue after the installation of Internet download manager because IDM has changed the IP settings that error comes so after uninstalling IDM from my PC and restarting the PC solve the problem. **SO uninstall any application which has changed the Internet Protocol settings like Internet download manager.**